# IPV6 settings server nic

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ipv6

I'm building a small network of 5 servers (2008R2) and for networking IPV4 settings are already set-up and working. (static IP's for all servers)

All the NICS have support for IPV6 but for now all of them have obtaining IP and DNS automatic for now. I'm not sure what I should do whit this situation.

I've read about IPV6 but its not easy stuff to understand so I'm not able to find how I can give my servers static IPV6 settings. (and if this is a good idea or not)
But leaving servers with automatic resolution of IP and DNS for this protocol doesn't sound good too.

I could also disable the support for IPV6 but I'm not sure if the services I'm running on all servers are using this and on the other hand this protocol is the future so maybe having it properly set-up is the better idea.

Can anybody guide me in the wonderful world of IPV6?

Solution (for me at least)
Mulaz pointed me to the fact if I was even using public IPV6 by running ipconfig /all and looking if I have records other then: link-local addresses for IPV6.
In my situation I didn't have any so per NIC I disabled the checkbox for IPV6 support to disable it.

Comment: This might seem harsh, but if you're not really sure what you're doing, the first place to start isn't a Q&A site about specific issues. I'd try looking at Google, there's literally thousands of resources out there that can help understand IPv6 better.

Comment: @growse doesn't sound harsh at all. And like I said above I did read in on the topic but for me the concept is not as easy as IPV4. So thats why I'm asking for advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need IPv6? Does your ISP provide you IPv6 connectivity? If not, then you can disable it. If it does, then you need to talk to them, to get information about your connectivity, and router and IP settings (your prefix/es, connecting segment info, etc.). If you use dns, you need to add AAAA records for your servers.

You'll also need an IPv6 capable firewall.

Comment: thanks. I will go and ask them first what my options are. And if I need it.. don't know I'm running services that can use them (like MS Exchange) but if it will hurt if I turn it off? That's my question :)

Comment: If you dont use it (you personally), then it wont hurt at all :) I dont know your setup, but if you only used ipv4 for all settings and connections etc., then you dont need ipv6. If you check "ipconfig -all", and you only have link-local addresses (fe80::something), and no public addresses (2xxx:* 3xxx:*), then nothing will change at all.

Comment: Hi Mulaz, ok looks like I only have link-local addresses so that clears things up. So disabling is the way to go. Is it enough to clear the checkbox for using IPV6 in the NIC properties?

Comment: If you haven't used those addresses in any configuration, you can just uncheck the ipv6 in the properties, yes. Then if you check the "ipconfig -all" again, there should be no more ipv6 addresses on that interface.